# Convert a scrambled Chinese string back to normal with R

Tags: r, string, scramble

When I download a pdf file, whose name should be something like

"论推理的要素.pdf",

from a website, it is scrambled into something like

"ÂÛÍÆÀíµÄÒªËØ.pdf".

I'm wondering whether it is possible using R to convert the scrambled string back to the normal one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# Save your locate:
Sys.getlocale()
# [1] "LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_India.1252"

# Change the locate to 'chinese' and convert the word
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="chinese")
print("ÂÛÍÆÀíµÄÒªËØ")
# [1] "论推理的要素"

# Restore
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="English_India.1252")
```

Comment: Thanks, Raja. Actually I have lots of such files. I'm wondering whether it is possible to use function  `iconv` or similar thing to convert them? Thanks.

Comment: I found a suggestion using shell function `iconv`, and it works for me: https://sspai.com/post/44360 (Sorry, it is in Chinese, but the script should be interpretable). But when I tried the R function `iconv`, it didn't succeed.